# How to link up files from grandchild directory down two levels from the current dir with PHP opendir?

Tags: php

I cannot seem to get the links that are populated from the directory scan to LINK up appropriately. When I click the populated link it is currently referencing the current directory instead of the grandchild directory here dir_2/dir_3. Any help would be very appreciated.

```
 <?php

  // These files will be ignored
  $excludedFiles = array (
'excludeMe.file',
'excludeMeAs.well'
);

// These file extensions will be ignored
$excludedExtensions = array (
  'html',
'xslt',
'htm',
'ahk',
'xsl',
'txt',
'xml'
);

// Make sure we ignore . and ..
$excludedFiles = array_merge($excludedFiles,array('.','..')); 

 // Convert to lower case so we are not case-sensitive
 for ($i = 0; isset($excludedFiles[$i]); $i++) $excludedFiles[$i] =        
 strtolower(ltrim($excludedFiles[$i],'.'));
  for ($i = 0; isset($excludedExtensions[$i]); $i++) $excludedExtensions[$i] =    
 strtolower($excludedExtensions[$i]);

  // Loop through directory
  $count = 0;
  if ($handle = opendir('dir_2/dir_3')) {
  while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
  $extn = explode('.',$file);
  $extn = array_pop($extn);
  // Only echo links for files that don't match our rules
  if (!in_array(strtolower($file),$excludedFiles) &&   
  !in_array(strtolower($extn),$excludedExtensions)) {
    $count++;
    print("<a href=\"".$file."\">".$file."</a><br />\n");
  }
}
echo '<br /><br /><a href="..">Return</a>';
closedir($handle);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append the directory you're looking at to the link.

```
$dir = 'dir_2/dir_3';
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
// snip
print("<a href=\"".$dir.$file."\">".$file."</a><br />\n");
```

Comment: I am gettin an error - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/content/65/7238265/html/Reports/dropdown.php on line 172 - this line - print("<a href=\""$dir.$file."\">".$file."</a><br />\n");

Comment: Oops, schoolboy, that one :P Copy it again, it was missing a concat (.) before $dir :)